# Java regex to remove SQL comments from a string

Tags: java, sql, regex

Hope someone can help me out with this one !

I have a sql file that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT UNIQUE (firstname,lastname)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

INSERT IGNORE INTO users (firstname,lastname) VALUES ('x','y');
/*
INSERT IGNORE INTO users (firstname,lastname) VALUES ('a','b');
*/
```

I have buit a web application that initializes a mysql database at startup with this function:

```
public static void initDatabase(ConnectionPool pool, File sqlFile){
    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;
    String mySb=null;
    try{
        con = pool.getConnection();
        mySb=IOUtils.copyToString(sqlFile);

        // We use ";" as a delimiter for each request then we are sure to have well formed statements
        String[] inst = mySb.split(";");

        st = con.createStatement();

        for(int i = 0; i<inst.length; i++){
            // we ensure that there is no spaces before or after the request string
            // in order not to execute empty statements
            if(!inst[i].trim().isEmpty()){
                st.executeUpdate(inst[i]);
            }
        }
        st.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }catch(SQLException e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }finally{
        SQLUtils.safeClose(st);
        pool.close(con);
    }
}
```

(This function was found on the web.  Author, please forgive me for not citing your name, I lost it !!)

It works perfectly as long as there is not SQL comment blocks.

The `copyToString()` function basically does what it says.
What I would like now is build a regex that will remove block comments from the string.  I only have block comments `/*  */` in the file, no `--`.

What I have tried so far:

```
mySb = mySb.replaceAll("/\\*.*\\*/", "");
```

Unfortunatly, I'm not very good at regex...

I get all the troubles of "The matched string look something like `/* comment */ real statement /* another comment*/` " and so on...

Comment: You need lazy operator `?` in your regex

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
mySb = mySb.replaceAll("/\\*.*?\\*/", "");
```

(notice the `?` which stands for "[lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)").

**EDIT**: To cover multiline comments, use this approach:

```
Pattern commentPattern = Pattern.compile("/\\*.*?\\*/", Pattern.DOTALL);
mySb = commentPattern.matcher(mySb).replaceAll("");
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: It seems to work for block comment that is on one line, but not for blocks which stand on multiple line !! Does the `.*?` also matches carriage return?

Comment: Ouch, you need to use a full-fledged `Pattern` instance using the `Pattern.DOTALL` flag. I will modify the answer shortly.

Comment: After having read the docs for `Pattern` class, it works, thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a reluctant qualifier like this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "The matched string look something like /* comment */ real statement /* another comment*/";
        System.err.println(s.replaceAll("/\\*.*?\\*/", ""));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following approach:

```
String s = "/* comment */ select * from XYZ; /* comment */";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("/\\*.*?\\*/", ""));
```

Outputs:

```
 select * from XYZ;
```

The `.*?` stands for use [Laziness Instead of Greediness](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) (that means the `.*` matches the largest string possible by default, i.e. is greedy => you have to configure it to be non-greedy using the `?` in the `.*?` expression).

Comment: thanks for the explanation of laziness and greediness. I at least learned something.  But see my comment on Alexander Pavlov post please.

Answer (score 1):

it won't work 100%

the comments can be a part of a valid string specified in the SQL and in that case they need to be kept...

I am just researching a solution... seems to be complicated

so far I have:

```
\G(?:[^']*?|'(?:[^']|'')*?'(?!'))*?\/\*.*?\*\/
```

but it matches all while I need to match the comment only... and just found out it could fail when preceded by a single-line comment... damn

Comment: ok, so now comments in strings won't be a problem anymore, but for the single-line comments before multi-line comments... I think a parser will really be easier: `(?:[^']*?|'(?:[^']|'')*?'(?!'))*?\K\/\*.*?\*\/`